# How to enlarge the header of a fancy page style?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I am using a `fancy` page style for my report.
I am using the following code to set the width of the body:

```
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.65cm, bottom=2.65cm]{geometry}
```

However, the bar in the header is not taking the same width.
I would like to know how to fix the width of the black bar in the header.

Comment: You should set `\pagestyle{fancy}` *after* the call to `geometry`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Thank you! I have a second question: how to remove the left title on this header? (and keep the right title of the header)

Comment: It seems that is a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117). Please ask another question on the main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you should put your pagestyle changes after the loading of `geometry`. If you still need to enlarge the header and/or footer, you can look for `\fancyhfoffset` in the `fancyhdr` [documentation](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=fancyhdr).

Here is an example of it in action, taken from the LaTeX Wikibook page on [Page Layout](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Page_Layout#Examples).

```
\fancypagestyle{fancybook}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    % Note the ## here. It's required because \fancypagestyle is making a macro
    % (\ps@fancybook).  If we just wrote #1, TeX would think that it's the argument
    % to \ps@fancybook, but \ps@fancybook doesn't take any arguments, so TeX would
    % complain with an error message.
    % You are not expected to understand this.
    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{\thesection\ ##1} }%
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter: ##1}{} }%
    % Increase the length of the header such that the folios
    % (typography jargon for page numbers) move into the margin
    \fancyhfoffset[LE]{6mm}% slightly less than 0.25in
    \fancyhfoffset[RO]{6mm}%
    % Put some space and a vertical par between the folio and the rest of the header
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\hskip3mm\vrule\hskip3mm\leftmark}%
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\hskip3mm\vrule\hskip3mm\thepage}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I have a second question: how to remove the left title on this header? (and keep the right title of the header)

Comment: See the examples on the linked page. Modifying `fancyhdr` page styles via appropriate `\.*mark` and `\mark.*` macros is one of the trickier aspects of using it.

Comment: The simplest is of course just to use `\fancyhead[LO]{}`. That should make the left side of the header on verso (odd-numbered) pages empty.